# Homomorphisms from a torsion module over an integral domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $R$ be an integral domain and $N$ a torsion $R$-module.

Claim: For any $R$-module $M$, $M$ is torsion-free if and only if $\text{Hom}_R(N,M) = 0$.

Is this claim true? I can prove one direction, but I'm stuck on the other one.

If $M$ is torsion-free then certainly $\text{Hom}_R(N,M) =0$ because for any $\phi\in\text{Hom}_R(N,M)$, we must have $\phi(N) \subseteq \text{Tor}(M) = 0$.

If $M$ is not torsion-free then it seems to me as if we should be able to construct a nonzero homomorphism from $N$ to $M$, but I don't know how to go about it and so I'm not sure if it's necessarily possible.

Comment: Your title says ‘ homomorphisms *from* a torsion module’, and you consider homomorphisms *to* a torsion module…

Comment: Right you are. I made a typo in my post. Several in fact.

Answer (score 1):

A single torsion module doesn't suffice: $N=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and $M=\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ are both torsion, but
$$
\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(N,M)=0
$$

What you want to prove is that $M$ is torsionfree if and only if, *for every* torsion module $N$, $\operatorname{Hom}_R(N,M)=0$.

This is essentially trivial, because you can consider the torsion submodule $t(M)$ of $M$:
$$
t(M)=\{x\in M:rx=0\text{ for some }r\ne0\}
$$
and $M$ is torsionfree if and only if $t(M)=0$.

Comment: Yeah I meant to write $\text{Hom}_R(N,M)$. Yeah I see the triviality now. It's kind of annoyingly trivial. Thanks